# Override nginx request headers with uwsgi_pass

Tags: nginx, uwsgi

Is there any way I can get nginx to ***not*** forward a specific request header to uwsgi?

I want to enable nginx basic auth, but if the `Authorization` header gets forwarded to my app it breaks things (for reasons, I won't go into). If it was just a simple `proxy_pass` I would be able to do `proxy_set_header Authorization "";` but I don't think this works with `uwsgi_pass` and there's no equivalent `uwsgi_set_header` as far as I can see.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try hide header and ignore header directives:

**uwsgi_hide_header**

> Syntax:   uwsgi_hide_header field; Default:   — Context:  http, server,
>   location
>
> By default, nginx does not pass the header fields “Status” and
>   “X-Accel-...” from the response of a uwsgi server to a client. The
>   uwsgi_hide_header directive sets additional fields that will not be
>   passed. If, on the contrary, the passing of fields needs to be
>   permitted, the uwsgi_pass_header directive can be used.

**uwsgi_ignore_headers**

> Syntax:   uwsgi_ignore_headers field ...; Default:    —
>
> Context:  http, server, location Disables processing of certain
>   response header fields from the uwsgi server. The following fields can
>   be ignored: “X-Accel-Redirect”, “X-Accel-Expires”,
>   “X-Accel-Limit-Rate” (1.1.6), “X-Accel-Buffering” (1.1.6),
>   “X-Accel-Charset” (1.1.6), “Expires”, “Cache-Control”, “Set-Cookie”
>   (0.8.44), and “Vary” (1.7.7).
>
> If not disabled, processing of these header fields has the following
>   effect:
>
> “X-Accel-Expires”, “Expires”, “Cache-Control”, “Set-Cookie”, and
>   “Vary” set the parameters of response caching; “X-Accel-Redirect”
>   performs an internal redirect to the specified URI;
>   “X-Accel-Limit-Rate” sets the rate limit for transmission of a
>   response to a client; “X-Accel-Buffering” enables or disables
>   buffering of a response; “X-Accel-Charset” sets the desired charset of
>   a response.

Comment: That's for response headers, not request headers.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably too late for you but for anyone who would have the same problem, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51207405/1365867) provides a valid solution.

In this case the `Authorization` header could be passed by using the following directive:

```
uwsgi_param  HTTP_Authorization "";
```