# Missing nginx headers in uWSGI application (flask)

Tags: docker, nginx, flask, uwsgi

My python application (`Flask`) runs behind `uWSGI` (application server), and in the front of `Nginx` (http server), and is packaged in `docker` container.
What I try to achieve is to forward real IP address from http server (`Nginx`) into my app server (`uWSGI`).

To do, so I specify `X-Real-IP` and `X-Forwarded-For` headers in my nginx config. Unfortunately, inspecting flask's `request.headers` I can only see
`Host` header and remaining two are missing.

The same setup works with `gunicorn`, and there my headers are present. Any idea how to fix it?

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name app.local;

  ## uWSGI setup for API
  location /api {
    include       /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass    unix:///var/run/app.uwsgi.sock;
    uwsgi_param   Host                  $host;
    uwsgi_param   X-Real-IP             $remote_addr;
    uwsgi_param   X-Forwarded-For       $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution. I just had to prefix my `X-HEADERS` with `HTTP`. Here is an example.

```
# From
uwsgi_param   X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
uwsgi_param   X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

# To
uwsgi_param   HTTP_X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
uwsgi_param   HTTP_X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

Comment: That's the voodoo that I do do :)